# How to assign a variable name to a worksheet in openpyxl?

Tags: python, openpyxl

In openpyxl 2.4.8, is it possible to give a created Excel worksheet a name that depends on user input, for example?

What I tried so far is the most obvious thing

```
from openpyxl import load_workbook
...
wb=load_workbook("Some_WB_name.xlsx")
ws=wb.create_sheet("Data_set_", int(some_user_input))
```

but it gives me a worksheet called just "Data_set_". I also checked the docs https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/2.5/index.html but did not find anything related there.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is not a good idea to pass user input directly into a library function. Much better to check it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[from this PDF documentation](https://media.readthedocs.org/pdf/openpyxl/latest/openpyxl.pdf), the `create_sheet` method has two optional arguments:

`create_sheet(title=None, index=None)`

This method will create a worksheet (at an optional index).

Parameters

- title – optional title of the sheet
- index (int) – optional position at which the sheet will be inserted

Your user input is being passed as the second parameter (`index`). If you need that input as part of the sheet name, you need to append that to the `title` parameter:

```
ws = wb.create_sheet('Data_set_' + str(some_user_input))
```